# Temp Collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, nosql-aggregation

Can we create Temp collections in MongoDB like we create Temp Table in SQL.

I know **$out & $merge** but collections created via **$out and $merge** will be replicated to the secondary nodes as well and hence would take unnecessary bandwidth and replication resources while creation and deletion.

Comment: No, temporary collections are not supported in MongoDB. If the tables are not too big and fits into your RAM , then it might be an option to put all data into an array variable.

Comment: but we can't perform aggregation pipelines on array variables!

Comment: Here's a [super kludgey way to transform an array into "documents"(mongoplayground.net)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8rAgACkHyPW "Click me!").  You can continue the aggregation pipeline with more stages.

Comment: Of course you can. You can use variable instead of almost every aggregation expression. In MongoDB release 5.1 you don't need any collection at all, see [$documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/documents/)